# Significance of <security enabled="false"/> tag in standalone-full.xml in JBoss

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

In our project we are using JBoss EAP 7.2. We are creating queues (Apache ActiveMQ Artemis) in `standalone-full.xml` and sending/receiving messages to/from those queues from applications developed using Spring Boot. But to send a message to queue we are adding the tag `<security enabled="false"/>` in the configuration of messaging subsystem of `standalone-full.xml`. If this tag is not added we are getting an error while connecting to the queue.

Now our requirement is to enable SSL while connecting to the broker. For that I was going through some of the articles and the steps to enable SSL security while connecting to the broker as I understood the following:

1. Add certificate and enable SSL in JBoss
2. Use `https-remoting` protocol for connecting to JBoss instead of the `http-remoting` protocol
3. Change the port as https port `8443` instead of `8080`

My question is will I have to remove the tag `<security enabled="false"/>` from messaging subsystem configuration in `standalone-full.xml` to connect to the broker using SSL? What is the use / significance of this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broker security and transport security are independent of each other so you can connect to the broker using SSL even if you're using `<security enabled="false"/>`.

However, I would **strongly** discourage you from using `<security enabled="false"/>`. This means that there is **no authentication or authorization** performed on any connection to the broker. In other words, any client which can reach the broker can send anything they want to the broker and consume anything they want from the broker. If you're using this strictly for development then relaxed security is usually fine (although not ideal), but this is a really bad idea for any production system.

Comment: When I am sending a message to MQ from Spring Boot application, I am providing the username and password (security.principal and security.credential). Still I am unable to connect to MQ with security enabled as true. Can you please suggest me what needs to be done to enable broker security?

Comment: Broker security is enabled by default so you can simply remove `<security enabled="false"/>` to enable it or set `<security enabled="true"/>`. If you've having issues beyond that I recommend you create a new question as that's quite different from the question you've asked here. If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help others who may have the same question in the future. Of course, if you create a new question I will help as much as I can there as well. Thanks!